# How to play a single audio file in activity even I Switch the activity ?

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool

I need to play a audio file in my Activity and If I change the Activity, the audio file should be play simultaneously.

I tried it using `MediaPlayer` but when I switch the Activity audio stop

What is the possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need something that will live longer than the Activity to hold the MediaPlayer. That can be you extending Application, you having some static object be a wrapper for the MediaPlayer, or you can have a Service that you control to use the MediaPlayer for you. Since the Application has a context you can use for your audio needs that's probably a fairly easy option.

If you don't want to mess with adding your extended Application to the manifest then I suggest going for a static object to hold the MediaPlayer for you and initializing it with the Application Context. In all cases just be careful that you manage the life cycle well and clean up.